# MooTools Top Panel not appearing

Tags: javascript, mootools

I am using [this](http://woork.blogspot.com/2008/03/sliding-top-panel-using-mootools_05.html) sliding top panel using mootools (for orientation, the code is basically the same).

I want it to appear when the page is loaded, means, index.html is loaded.
I achieved this simply by adding the corresponding JavaScript to index.html:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.addEvent('domready', function(){
    var mySlide = new Fx.Slide('top-panel');
    $('toggle').addEvent('click', function(e){
    e = new Event(e);
    mySlide.toggle();
    e.stop();
    });
    });
</script>
```

(Of course this is also the top-panel itself)
When you click a link in this top panel, a new page [will be loaded into a specified div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1395830/why-isnt-this-javascript-executed), and *then*, the top panel should be hidden.

I think you can do this by adding

```
var mySlide = new Fx.Slide('top-panel').hide();
```

or

```
mySlide.hide();
```

in some JavaScript. I think it should execute, when the [ahah.js](http://pastebay.com/52986)-javascript is done loading the content into the div, I tried adding both the JavaScript quoted above and the two variations of mySlide.hide() in ahah.js. (into ahahDone(), after the last getElementById).

Using this setup, I get the following rendering. (This is after clicking the corresponding link which loads content from an html-file into a div and clicking on the "More (mehr)" link on top of the page which should slide down the top panel.) But only the button which is visible always (sub-panel) slides down and is visible, the actual panel content does not show up.

Any ideas? It would be great, if you could leave an answer with a short explanation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like a scoping problem. You declare `mySlide` inside an anonymous function, and its scope will be limited to that function. Later, when $('toggle') is clicked, the event that is fired is outside the scope of that function so it does not have access to `mySlide`.

A quick fix (if you don't mind using globals) could be declaring `var mySlide=null` in the main javascript so that you have a closure, and then change your current `var mySlide=new Fx.Slide(...)` to just `mySlide=new Fx.Slide(..)`

(or it could be something else entirely...)

Comment: scoping? i don't think so, not here. the event function should inherit the parent function's variables just fine. 

His issue is that he uses Fx.Slide which is a mootools 1.11 method but is deprecated in 1.2 (which he also uses, so it has overwritten the class).

Comment: Sure, the event function would inherit variables from its parent. But the converse is happening here. He is creating mySlide inside the event function and trying to access it later from outside.